# Rancher Unable to connect Cluster Ip from another project

Tags: networking, rancher, isolation

I'm using rancher 2.3.5 on centos 7.6 
in my cluster the "project Network isolation" is enable.

I have 2 projects:
In the projet 1, I have deployed one apache docker that listens to  port 80 on cluster IP 
[enter image description [network isolation config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjsqB.png)
In the second project, I unable to connect the projet 1 cluster IP 
Is the project Network isolation block also the traffic for the cluter IP between the two projects.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have correctly pointed out how a ClusterIP works from the standpoint of just Kuberentes, however the OP specifies that Rancher is involved.

Rancher provides the concept of a "Project" which is a collection of Kubernetes namespaces. When Rancher is set to enable "Project Network Isolation", Rancher manages Kubernetes Network Policies such that namespaces in different Projects can not exchange traffic on the cluster overlay network.

This creates the situation observed by the OP. When "Project Network Isolation" is enabled, a ClusterIP in one Project is unable to exchange traffic with a traffic source in a different Project, even though they are in the same Kubernetes Cluster.

There is a brief note about this by Rancher documentation:
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-provisioning/rke-clusters/options/
and while that document seems to limit the scope to Pods, because Pods and ClusterIPs are allocated from the same network it applies to ClusterIPs as well.

Answer (score 0):

K8s Cluster IPs are restricted for communication with in the cluster. A good read on the CLusterIP, Node Port and the load balancer can be found at https://www.edureka.co/community/19351/clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer-different-from-each-other .

If your intention is to make the services in the 2 different cluster communicate, then go for the below methods.

1. Deploy a overlay network for your Nodegroup
2. Cluster peering